# How do I build, deploy and debug standalone java app on remote machine?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, ssh, intellij-14

How do I build, deploy and debug standalone java app on remote machine with IDEA ?

I have remote machine with certain hardware device connected to it. I want to develop standalone Java app on my PC, build it locally but the app should be deployed and running on remote machine accessible via SSH. Thus I'll be using Java remote debug.

I've googled extensively but couldn't understand if it's possible to achieve in IDEA (even though IDEA allows to do so for java servlet containers). I tried "Remote SSH External Tools" plugin. I'm not sure what to specify in following dialog (which seems to have [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140166))

[image]

What options do I have ?

Answer (score 0):

If the machine is only reachable via SSH you need to do two things:

- Configure your java application for remote debugging
- Connect to the application via SSH

This tutorial should get you going: [Remote Debug of a Java App Using SSH Tunneling](http://arjon.es/2014/03/27/remote-debug-java-app-using-ssh-tunneling-without-opening-server-ports/)

Comment: Thank you. The question is how to automate process of deploying and launching the app on remote machine. Attaching debugger to existing process is obvious.